# Angular Views are not Loading

Tags: angularjs

The pages aren't loading in my ng-view. All the clicked links come up as just blank. What am I doing wrong? I think I have all my routes put correctly. Thanks in advance.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="soolApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hi. I'm Dan Karlin.</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#promo"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> Example 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#rain"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> Example 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

<div id="main">

    <div ng-view></div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var soolApp = angular.module('soolApp', ['ngRoute']);

soolApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        .when('/promo', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/promo.html',
            controller  : 'promoController'
        })

        .when('/rain', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/rain.html',
            controller  : 'rainController'
        });
});

soolApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
});

soolApp.controller('promoController', function($scope) {
});

soolApp.controller('rainController', function($scope) {
});
```

So, I'm at a loss. I have a job interview on Monday and was putting together this angular app for that purpose.

Comment: provide a plunker link, so others can debug issue and help to resolve it.

Comment: @Dan : Did my answer help ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check your `console` of browser. You have done everything right. Here [is the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/e62Lg4cIbNMHq1MCAW1d?p=preview) I created from your example. Its working. Only thing you should look into is the location of `html` files which might be giving 404 error.

And, **Best of luck for the interview ;)**